# Display warning message in an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, range, version

I have a regex type of field (^\d+.\d+.\d+$) in an HTML form. If a user enters any of the following versions below, we need the field to display a warning message. Is this possible?

- 4.0.x to 4.5.6
- 4.9.9
- 4.9.11
- 5.1.0
- 6.x.x

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fx(inp){
    string = inp.value;
    regex = /^\d+.\d+.\d+$/;
    msg = 'your message';
    if (regex.test(string)&&inrange(string)){
      alert(msg);
    }       
}
    
function inrange(string){
  ver = string.split('.').map(v => parseInt(v));
  if (['4.9.9', '4.9.11','5.1.0'].includes(string)){return true;}
  if (ver[0] == 6){return true;}
  if((ver[0] == 4)){
    if(ver[1] < 5){return true;}
    if((ver[1]==5)&&(ver[2]<=6)){return true;}
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' onfocusout='fx(this)'>
```

Yes, it is possible.

You just need to:

1. Trigger JavaScript function (e.g. onchange, onfocusout, onblur...) in the input tag.
2. Check the input value against your regex and other criteria.
3. Prompt your warning message accordingly.

Comment: How do you check the input value if it's within the range?

Comment: Edited the answer with an additional checking function. Hope this helps~